# Bitbucket webhook to Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, webhooks

I want to configure Jenkins build on every commit to specific branch. I am trying to use **Bitbucket Webhook to Jenkins** but it is not working as per expectations. To run it successfully I need to select following two options in Jenkins job
**1.Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket**
and **2. Poll SCM(keeping it blank)**

and in webhook as below screenshot

[image]

When I untick **Omit Branch Name** it gives following error.

[image]

When I mention branch name to build from in Advance Configurations to Build Options : as below
[image]

it give following error in logs and do not trigger any build in Jenkins.

```
2017-07-28 19:18:49,382 ERROR [AtlassianEvent::thread-3] XXXXXXX @4NXRG4x1158x165x0 s2l8ua 10.229.17.70 "PUT /rest/api/latest/projects/STCPLAY/repos/mavensample/browse/pom.xml HTTP/1.1" c.a.s.i.e.AsyncBatchingInvokersTransformer There was an exception thrown trying to dispatch event 'com.atlassian.bitbucket.event.content.FileEditedEvent[source=com.atlassian.stash.internal.content.DefaultContentService@72ae21ba]' for the invoker 'SingleParameterMethodListenerInvoker{method=public void com.nerdwin15.stash.webhook.RepositoryChangeListener.onRefsChangedEvent(com.atlassian.bitbucket.event.repository.RepositoryRefsChangedEvent), listener=com.nerdwin15.stash.webhook.RepositoryChangeListener@356e810b}'
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.atlassian.bitbucket.repository.RefChange.getRefId()Ljava/lang/String;. Listener: com.nerdwin15.stash.webhook.RepositoryChangeListener event: com.atlassian.bitbucket.event.content.FileEditedEvent
    at com.atlassian.event.internal.SingleParameterMethodListenerInvoker.invoke(SingleParameterMethodListenerInvoker.java:55)
    at com.atlassian.stash.internal.event.AsyncBatchingInvokersTransformer$AsyncInvokerBatch.invoke(AsyncBatchingInvokersTransformer.java:109)
    at com.atlassian.event.internal.AsynchronousAbleEventDispatcher$1$1.run(AsynchronousAbleEventDispatcher.java:38)
    at com.atlassian.sal.core.executor.ThreadLocalDelegateRunnable.run(ThreadLocalDelegateRunnable.java:34)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 frame trimmed
```

Anyone faced this issue and fixed it ?
Or
there is any other better way to trigger builds on commits pushed to bitbucket on specific branch.

Comment: Is this a config.xml job or a pipeline job? The solutions differ based on the jenkins job type.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

A couple of suggestions:

1. You may need to ensure that the branch spec on the Jenkins job (`Branches to build`) matches the branches that you specify in `Branch Options` in the BitBucket plugin configuration.
2. As far as I know, the `Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket` option is irrelevant in this case.

You can find more detailed instructions here - https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/226568007-How-to-Trigger-Non-Multibranch-Jobs-from-BitBucket-Server-

Comment: This answer assumes the OP is using the Bitbucket plugin on the Jenkins side of the fence.  The Bitbucket Server Webhook To Jenkins plugin allows you to use either the Git plugin or the Bitbucket plugin on the Jenkins side, so it does not offer a full answer to the question.